# Mvc -issue while calling controller after deployment , getting 500 internal server error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis, kendo-grid

I'm facing one different issue which i never faced.
I have a kendo grid which contains two links in two separate columns. When i'm clicking on one link its working as expected and calling action method, but the other link not going controller says 500 internal server error. Other thing is this is happening only after deployed the site.
First method calling:

```
$.get('/Admin/UserPresetDesigns?data='+data, function (data) {
    $('#divData').html('');
    $('#divData').html(data);
    $('#divData').show();
    $('#divData').fadeIn('fast');
})
```

Action Method:  `

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UserPresetDesigns(string data)
{
    // obj1 will be filled here
    return PartialView("UserPresetDesigns",obj1);
}
```

Second method calling:

```
$.get('/Admin/UserDetails?data='+data, function (data) {
    $('#divData').html('');
    $('#divData').html(data);
    $('#divData').show();
    $('#divData').fadeIn('fast');
})
```

Action method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UserDetails(string data)
{
    return PartialView("UserDetails",obj1);
}
```

I'm able to call both methods in local, once deployed in iis.. not able to call the second action method. responds with 500 internal server error

Comment: I'm seeing following error in console.- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) - http://localhost:8001/Admin/GetUserDetail?data=6&_=1481340912859

Comment: It means your throwing an exception on the server. Use your browser tools (Network tab) to inspect the response which will include the details of the error (and your comment says its calling ../GetUserDetail?...` but none of your code relates to that method)

Comment: that is Userdetail method. I'm seeing following error in console.- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) - localhost:8001/Admin/UserDetail?data=6&_=1481340912859 .

Comment: Not the console! - the Network tab - inspect the response

Comment: under net work tab Response header :HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: public, no-store, max-age=0, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Sat, 10 Dec 2016 04:54:30 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 10 Dec 2016 04:54:30 GMT
Vary: *
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 10 Dec 2016 04:54:32 GMT
Content-Length: 276

Comment: I couldn't add screen shot here. And response copied from Network tab:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <hgroup>
        <h1>Error.</h1>
        <h2>An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
    </hgroup>
</body>
</html>

Comment: It does not matter - the response will tell you exactly what the exception is (we cannot debug your code - you have not even shown it)